# How to control modifications to work with a remote server and a local server using git

Tags: css, git, version

I am doing a very simple project with HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have to load some text fonts that are stored directly on the server with a different folder structure.
So when developing locally on my computer I am using the sources directly from a very simple top folder, something like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Myfont;
    src: url("./fonts/font.otf");
}
```

But when I have to deliver the project I must replace it with something like:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: Myfont;
    src:url("./FrontAPP/Banner/BannerFixed/Fonts/font.otf");
}
```

Is there a way for git to handle these changes, **something like a production version and a development version without using branches**?

Answer (score 0):

Many things.

First, you should check that your font is available on CDNs such as [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com).

Next, why your fonts have to be in a different folder in development and production mode? It'll be easiest to keep your development structure for the production. This is usually the way to do it.

Finally, git doesn't use 'dev' and 'prod' version, the only way to create it is for example to create a `develop` branch for development version and the default `master` branch for production version

Comment: Thank you,
The source is not available on CDN because it is a private source from the company.

The fonts are in a different folder since my product must go inside an embeddable of type `<iframe>` which uses the fonts of the bigger project, therefore I am developing separately my `<iframe>` but when I put it on the server I want you to use that folder model.

That being the case, I think it is the only way to solve the problem by leaving the folder structure in _master_ and as I have it in _developmet_ thanks @blyndusk!